Problem with webscraping using selenium and beautifulsoup
I'm creating a price comparison website for my uni project. I'm trying to print the items and the price from this website https://www.lotuss.com.my/en/category/fresh-produce?sort=relevance:DESC but I got this error:
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not callable
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\Price\test.py", line 36, in <module>
    grocery_items = soup.findall('div', class_='product-grid-item')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

This is the code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

service = Service(executable_path='C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Open the webpage
driver.get('https://www.lotuss.com.my/en/category/fresh-produce?sort=relevance:DESC')

# Wait for the page to fully load
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe"))
    )
    print("Please solve the CAPTCHA manually in the opened browser window.")
finally:

    input("Press Enter after solving the CAPTCHA...")

    html_text = driver.page_source

    driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
grocery_items = soup.findall('div', class_='product-grid-item')
grocery_price = soup.findall('span', class_='sc-kHxTfl hwpbzy')

print(grocery_items)
print(grocery_price)


Flagging to close as a typo.

The error is caused by using an incorrect method for the soup object. The method should be find_all instead of findall.
Code should be as below:
grocery_items = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-grid-item')
grocery_price = soup.find_all('span', class_='sc-kHxTfl hwpbzy')

I tested your code and there are few more issues. Once you have fixed the error asked in this question, you may notice nothing gets printed on the console. Do as below:

By default, selenium doesn't open browser in full screen, this may result in elements being not visible sometimes and may not locate all the targeted elements. Hence open chrome in full screen using below code:
driver.get('https://www.lotuss.com.my/en/category/fresh-produce?sort=relevance:DESC')
driver.maximize_window()


The last line of your code is just printing the HTML
print(grocery_items)
print(grocery_price)

Instead you need to print the text values of the HTML. Use code as below:
for item in grocery_items:
    print(item.get_text(strip=True))

for price in grocery_price:
    print(price.get_text(strip=True))




tysm for the answer . i also have another question how do i continue scraping if the website doesn't load fully cause it only loads parts of it when scrolling

Selenium can only scrape elements which are loaded and are visible on screen. To continue scraping you need to scroll down the page and load elements.

The error in your code stems out from the call to soup.findall. You have to replace this with a call to soup.find_all, or even better use CSS selectors with BS4 directly using soup.select.
Taking a look at the website, it seems you can use the back-end API to get the data directly, and skip over parsing the HTML from Selenium.
import json

import requests

url = "https://api-o2o.lotuss.com.my/lotuss-mobile-bff/product/v2/products"
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en"}
q = {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 300,
    "filter": {
        "categoryUrlKey": "fresh-produce",
    },
    "websiteCode": "malaysia_hy",
}
q = json.dumps(q)
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={"q": q})
response.raise_for_status()

You can play around with the values of limit and offset to iterate over different results.
Best!
